# Azure Front Door - Time for changes to be online

Tags: azure, updates, azure-front-door

I am currently testing the Azure Front Door functionnality and was wondering if any changes takes a long time to be saved and available online?

For example, I have changed the backend URL of my backend pool and when I access the Front Door URL, it still redirects me to the old backend URL.

I have tried clearing browser and front door cache without success.  It has been almost an hour since I have saved my changes.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updates to configuration usually take 3-5 minutes to propagate globally.  Changes to your site content may require a purge of the CDN cache.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-caching#cache-purge